# ipython warning message - Linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ipython

When I try and execute 'ipython' from Linux shell by typing 'ipython' at the command prompt, it gives me the following message-

> Error processing line 1 of
>   /home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib-2.2.3-py3.6-nspkg.pth:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 174, in addpackage
>         exec(line)
>       File "", line 1, in 
>       File "", line 568, in module_from_spec   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
>   'loader'
>
> Remainder of file ignored Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018,
>   11:32:17)  Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more
>   information IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?'
>   for help.

I have a Linux x86_64 Ubuntu OS [18.04] system.
Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No exact idea. I have Ubuntu 18.04, too, and I use Python 3.7.1. You can try it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3.7
$ python3.7 -m pip ipython
$ python3.7 -m pip matplotlib
$ python3.7 -m pip numpy
```